# Salesforce1 App Winter15 issue publisher actions not working

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

I have the big issue with the Salesforce1 app for a few days. The style is rendering wrong and the publisher actions are not working :/
This problem occurs in the Browser (/one/one.app) and also in the native android/iOs app!!

Maybe there is a way to reinstall the Salesforce1 Mobile Components for my environment ? I still have this issue for all standard/custom objects...

Thanks a lot for any information!

Kind Regards
Daniel

---

since the Salesforce Winter15 Release from 5th of September the Salesforce1 mobile Browser App have a new look&feel. There is no plus icon for the publisher actions...

[image]

Currently the google Chrome Browser is not supported for the browser version of the moible app.
The prefer to use the newest version of Firefox.

You could find informations about the new look&feel of the Salesforce1 mobile app in the Winter15 Release Notes: https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_winter15_release_notes.pdf

Comment: Have you tried debugging the issue at your end? Do you see any errors in the browser console? What happens when you click on any publisher action?

Comment: The Google Chrome Developer Console said:Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest https://cs17.salesforce.com/l%2C%2dRUENqF9PDlyH21g%22%7D/app.manifest one.app:1
Application Cache Checking event one.app:1

Comment: And when i clicking on the publisher actions: Application Cache NoUpdate event

Comment: Maybe is there a was to reinstall the Salesforce1 components in my environment? Because i still have this issue all Objects custom and standard too...

Comment: I found the rise of this behavior: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49048/salesforce1-mobile-browser-app-winter15

Answer (score 3):

I believe this has to do with the Salesforce1 caching behavior. You can verify if you have a lot of cached data by going to `Settings | Offline Cache` in the Salesforce1 navigation menu.

[image]

Logout from your Salesforce1 app so that the cache is destroyed and it should work. If it does not, I would recommend raising a case with Salesforce support.

Comment: You could find informations about the new look&feel of the Salesforce1 mobile app in the Winter15 Release Notes: https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_winter15_release_notes.pdf