# Account Detail page not opening up in Salesforce1

Tags: rest-api, salesforce1-app

I am not sure why, but the Account Detail page is not opening in Salesforce1 mobile app. When I click on an Account, it shows the loading symbol and then a blank page is displayed.

I have customised this using a VF page and this page has got 3 REST API calls being made whenever the page is loaded. And I could see the detail page when opened via login.salesforce.com in the desktop browser but it doesn't happen when did the same using Salesforce1.

Need suggestions to fix this.

Comment: Can you run it in chrome using the /one/one.app URL and see what errors do you get in the Chrome console?

Comment: @GauravKheterpal I did run as per your comment above and this is what I got:
Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest https://na11.salesforce.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22o…JQyVHzg%22%7D%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22Tx1IuJEex0hXfP8Rt4IcdA%22%7D/app.manifest one.app:454
Application Cache Checking event one.app:454

Refused to display 'https://c.na11.visual.force.com/apex/AccountView_VF?id=001G000001eanAyIAI&i…rigin=https%3A%2F%2Fna11.salesforce.com&sfdcIFrameHost=web&sfdc.override=1' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Answer (score 3):

One of the reasons for this behavior is a stale cache.  Try clearing it by going to `Settings | Offline Cache` in the Salesforce1 navigation menu.

Logout from your Salesforce1 app so that the cache is destroyed and see if it works.

[image]

Similar issue described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48742/salesforce1-app-winter15-issue-publisher-actions-not-working).

Comment: I tried what you mentioned in your above comment, but it didn't help me. I have over-written the Leads,Accounts, Contacts and Opportunities with Visualforce pages and only those that are having Visualforce are not opening in Salesforce1 while those with standard layouts are showing up.